# JQuery Pop up and JSON parsing not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, magnific-popup

I have built a dog naming tool through jquery. It was requested that a json file with all the names be added into the tool. For some reason now that I have converted to use the JSON file, it's no longer working. Here is the code for HTML and jquery:

```
 <div class="dnt-container-mobile seasonal-bg-dark">
<h1 class="mobile-heading">Dog Name Finder</h1>
<h1 class="wide-heading"><!-- <span class="logo teal icon-akc-logo dnt-logo"></span> -->Dog Name Finder</h1>
<form class="dnt-tool" id="dnt" name="dnt">
    <div class="dnt-overlay">
        <input id="male" name="gender" type="radio" value="Male" />
            <label for="male">Male</label> 
        <input data-id="594" id="female" name="gender" type="radio" value="Female" />
            <label for="female">Female</label> 
        <input checked="checked" data-id="0" id="all" name="gender" type="radio" value="All" />
            <label for="all">All</label> 
        <select>
            <option data-id="0" value="/dog-name-finder/">Select a Category</option>
            <option data-id="0" value="/dog-name-finder/">All</option>
            <option value="/dog-name-finder/baby/">Baby</option>
            <option data-id="602" value="/dog-name-finder/celebrity/">Celebrity</option>
            <option data-id="603" value="/dog-name-finder/cute/">Cute</option>
            <option data-id="598" value="/dog-name-finder/disney/">Disney</option>
            <option data-id="600" value="/dog-name-finder/fancy/">Fancy</option>
            <option data-id="605" value="/dog-name-finder/most-popular/">Most Popular</option>
            <option data-id="599" value="/dog-name-finder/presidential/">Presidential</option>
            <option data-id="597" value="/dog-name-finder/techy/">Techy</option>
            <option data-id="596" value="/dog-name-finder/television/">Television</option>
            <option data-id="606" value="/dog-name-finder/trendy/">Trendy</option>
            <option data-id="595" value="/dog-name-finder/unisex/">Unisex</option>
            <option data-id="604" value="/dog-name-finder/video-game/">Video Game</option> 
        </select>
    </div><!-- end of dnt-overlay -->
    <div class="dnt-btn">
        <button id="submit" type="submit">Show Names</button>
    </div><!-- end of dnt btn -->
    </form><!-- end of dnt-tool -->
  </div><!-- end of dnt-container-mobile -->

   <div class="white-popup mfp-hide" id="dnt-popup">
    <div class="popup-logo">
   <a class="logo teal icon-logo"></a>
</div><!-- end of logo -->
<h1>Most Popular Dog Names</h1>
<img src="gender-all.png" id="dnt-all-img" alt=
all puppies">
<img src="female-puppy.png" id="dnt-female-img" alt="Female puppy">
<img src="male-puppy.png" id="dnt-male-img" alt="Male puppy">
<div class="results-list">
    <ul>
    </ul>
</div><!-- end of results list -->
<div class="more-btn">
    <div class="short-btn"><a href="/dog-name/">Tap to See More Names</a></div>
    <div class="long-btn"><a href="/dog-name/">Get More Names on Dog Name Finder</a></div>
</div><!-- end of dnt btn -->
```

Here is the JQuery portion:

```
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/0.9.9/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
         $('#dnt').submit(function(e){
               var cat_id = $('.dnt-overlay > select > option:selected').data('id') || 0;
           var cat_title = $('.dnt-overlay > select > option:selected').text() || 'All';
           if (cat_id === 0)
           {
              cat_title = 'All';
           }
           var dnt_url = $('.dnt-overlay > select > option:selected').val();
           var gender = $('.dnt-overlay > [name=gender]:checked').data('id') || 0;
           var gender_title = $('.dnt-overlay > [name=gender]:checked').val() || 'All';
           var title = cat_title;
           var html = '';

          var params = '';

          if(window.innerWidth <= 320)
          {
           params = '?limit=18';
          }
          else
          {
          params = '?limit=21';
          }


         if (cat_id > 0)
         {
         params += '&' + 'cat_id=' + cat_id;
         }

         if (gender > 0 && cat_title != 'Gender Agnostic' && cat_title != 'Unisex' && cat_title != 'Male' && cat_title != 'Female')
    {
        title += ' ' + gender_title;
        //params += '&' + 'gender=' + gender;
        if(cat_title == 'All')
        {
            dnt_url += gender_title.toLowerCase() + '/';
        }
        else
        {
            dnt_url += '?gender=' + gender_title.charAt(0).toLowerCase();
        }
    }

    title += ' Dog Names';

    $('#dnt-popup > h1').text(title);
    $('#dnt-popup > .more-btn').find('a').attr('href',dnt_url);



    e.preventDefault(); // We don't need to send the form, because it's all local
    if($('#male').is(':checked')) { // Check if male is checked
        $('#dnt-popup').removeClass('dnt-all').removeClass('dnt-female').addClass('dnt-male');
    } else if($('#female').is(':checked')) { // Check if female is checked 
        $('#dnt-popup').removeClass('dnt-all').removeClass('dnt-male').addClass('dnt-female');
    } else if($('#all').is(':checked')) { // Check if all is checked
        $('#dnt-popup').removeClass('dnt-female').removeClass('dnt-male').addClass('dnt-all');
    }
    $.ajax({
      dataType: "json",
      url: "dnt.json"
    })
      .done(function( data ) {

        $.each(data, function( index, value ) {
          html +='<li>' + value.title + '</li>';
        });

        $('#dnt-popup > .results-list > ul').html(html);

        $.magnificPopup.open({ // open pop up for male
                items: {
                src: '#dnt-popup',
                type: 'inline'

                },//item
                mainClass: 'animated slideInRight'
        });///popup open


      });   

});///submit function 


$('#dnt-popup > .more-btn > .long-btn > a, #dnt-popup > .more-btn > .short-btn > a').on("click",function(){

    var cat_id = $('.dnt-overlay > select > option:selected').data('id') || 0;
    var cat_title = $('.dnt-overlay > select > option:selected').text() || 'All';
    if (cat_id === 0)
    {
        cat_title = 'All';
    }

    var gender_title = $('.dnt-overlay > [name=gender]:checked').val() || 'All';

    }); //event for click to DNT landing page


  });///submit function 
  });//JQuery
 </script>
```

sample data from the dnt.json file:

```
    [
      {
        "Name": "Aaliyah",
        "Female": 594,
        "Baby": 601
      },
     {
        "Name": "Abby",
        "Female": 594
     },
    {
        "Name": "Abe",
        "Male": 593,
        "Video Games": 604
    },
   {
         "Name": "Abigail",
         "Female": 594,
         "Baby": 601
    },
   {
         "Name": "Abu",
         "Male": 593,
         "Disney": 598
   },
  {
         "Name": "Ace",
         "Male": 593,
         "Fancy": 600,
         "Cool": 611
   },
  {
      "Name": "Ace",
      "Male": 593,
      "Fancy": 600,
      "Cool": 611
   },
   {
      "Name": "Action",
      "Male": 593,
      "Female": 594,
      "Agnostic": 595
   },
   {
       "Name": "Ada",
       "Female": 594,
       "German": 610
    },
    {
      "Name": "Adalyn",
      "Female": 594,
      "Baby": 601
    },
  ]
```

Is there something I'm overlooking? Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: could you include a sample json file?

Comment: Sure I'll add it @IrkenInvader

Comment: Could you please remove all unnecessary "noise" to create a [**minimal**, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/); _"it's no longer working"_ -> Any errors in the console? What exactly is not working?

Comment: all necessary code is there, plus there was no console error. @Andreas

Answer (score 0):

When I run this code (after cleaning up some syntax errors) I hit this error:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 54 column 3 of
>   the JSON data

This is because of the comma here

```
    {
      "Name": "Adalyn",
      "Female": 594,
      "Baby": 601
    }, // <-- this comma
  ]
```

When I remove that comma, the code still doesn't exactly work, but it does *something* when I click 'Show names'.

For reference, the way I debugged it was to add this code to the $.ajax call:

```
.fail(function(a,b,c) {
    console.log(a);
    console.log(b);
    console.log(c);
})
```

This showed me that the `done` segment was never running, because the json was not formatted correctly.

Comment: Hmmm thanks, definitely a step in the right direction